# Help me understand this quote: "There are two kinds of leaders, cowboys and shepherds. Cowboys drive and shepherds lead."

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, quotations

I came across a quote by JP Warren

> *There are two kinds of leaders, cowboys and shepherds. Cowboys drive and shepherds lead.*

Question 1: Why are cowboys called leaders in the very first clause because the later part of the quote don't prove them leaders.

Question 2: If cowboys drive livestock, they lead them, don't they? And if shepherds lead livestock, they drive them, don't they?

The meaning of *lead* and *drive* ***in this context*** is the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think your deduction "drive and lead are the same (in this context)" is not sound. To make the fallacy more obvious, I could say this, "There are two kinds of leaders. Those who do lead and those who do not." I think it's clear that *do not lead* and *lead* in this context do not have the same meaning.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe what's meant here is that cowboys lead from behind, compelling the cattle to go before them, while shepherds go ahead themselves, and their sheep go after, following their example.

Thus a *cowboy leader* will rely on harsh methods to compel other people to execute tasks, while a *shepherd leader* will rely predominantly on inspiration, not force.

Comment: I'm speechless. However, cowboys generally lead the cows and other animals not specifically sheep. That's what I think but in any case, the explanation in this answer clarifies my doubts!

Comment: Oops. Indeed, cowboys deal with cows. (0:

Comment: @MaulikV -- yes, it's a terrible proverb.  It relies on fairly obscure cultural expectations of how different species of livestock are treated, and it implicitly disapproves of the cowboy style (the opposite of American cultural expectations, at least).  For a better illustration of the same idea, see [here](http://f.kulfoto.com/pic/0001/0044/151uJ43757.jpg).

Comment: It's especially obnoxious when the shepherd relies on his lackeys (i.e. sheepdogs) to perform the exact same function that cowboys do directly.

Comment: Note that the term _cowboy_ is (mostly) revered in American culture, as a symbol of ruggedness, independence, and manliness. In most of the world, in contrast, a "cowboy" is a loud, dirty, destructive lowlife who won't follow the rules, riding into town with sixguns blazing for the purpose of getting drunk and bedding a whore. A pilot or mariner who causes trouble for others by not conforming to the rules is often referred to as a cowboy.

Comment: @Malvolio - I disagree that it's a "terrible proverb." It's merely an analogy, not a proverb; like any analogy, it works fine so long as you understand the cultural background – which may mean it's more suitable for a particular audience. King David wrote that the Lord's "rod and staff" brought comfort, which makes sense, seeing that the words came from someone who spent many days and nights as a shepherd, but often requires some additional clarification and interpretation for the 21st century reader who has only seen sheep at a county fair. That doesn't make David's words a terrible proverb.

Comment: (cont.) Warren is a church pastor, so presumably he's speaking to members of the church, who are already familiar with analogies concerning sheep, from David and the Good Shepherd. I'd wager he's talking about leaders in the church, not leaders in the business world, and he's trying to say that church leaders need to be less like a cowboy and more like a shepherd. Considering most church workers are volunteers and not paid staff, that's probably true. I don't know if a church leader can effectively treat volunteers on Sunday the same way a boss treats employees Monday through Friday.

Comment: @PhilPerry -- Americans have the same view of cowboys as everyone else, we just admire them for those qualities.

Answer (score 5):

Cowboys use intimidation and fear to get animals to go in the desired direction (think sharp cries, and the sound of whips cracking). The cattle run in front of them.

Sheep follow behind their shepherd with a spirit of trust.

*Lead* and *drive* and not the same in this context. One is done from the front, and the other is done from behind.

In the context of management styles, the quote is contrasting those who manage with a spirit of intimidation vs those who lead in a more gentler manner.

Comment: I don't think you can whip cows.  I mean, you can, but I don't think it will help.

Comment: Ever hear of a bullwhip? Driving cattle, whips _can_ be used, but more often the cowboy on his horse blocks the cow from going where he doesn't want it to go.

Comment: @Malvolio - I never said anything about whipping cows. I only mentioned the [noise](http://www.americancowboy.com/culture/herd-cattle-whip).

Answer (score 5):

[image: boss and leader]

in addition to the other answers, boss of course is the cowboy and leader is the shepherd

Answer (score 1):

Basically it illustrates the difference in two styles of leadership, one driving the team, using force, prodding, intimidation, another leading from the behind, not too high profile, but motivating the team to do well.

The Cowboy here is the high profile leader, who leads from the front, seeks to project himself on to the team. His style is often authoritarian, in fact to the extent of pissing off his employees. He gets his people to do things, using a mix of intimidation, force, domination.

The Shepherd on the other hand is more low key, he believes in guiding the team, allowing them to work at their own pace, giving them more freedom. He does not believe in hand holding, he believes in letting the team members take their own decisions, and giving guidance where necessary. But at the same time, he ensures that ultimately individual interests are reconciled with team interests. You rarely see the sheep going out of line, under the shepherd's guidance.

Comment: That's not so :(

Comment: @Maulik - Strange. First you ask for help understanding a quote (which would imply you don't really understand it very well), but then you refute an answer, basically labeling it as wrong. How did you manage to acquire such expertise in a mere matter of hours? And what do you find erroneous in this answer? Personally, I think it's a pretty good answer that contains some very good differentiations.

Comment: @J.R. -- I think he is talking about how cowboys and shepherds really do their jobs, not how the proverb is supposed to be interpreted.

Comment: @Malvolio - in the context of the O.P.'s question, I don't know how you can discuss one without discussing the other.

Comment: @J.R. I had a problem with the *position* described in this answer that might have impact on the quote's overall meaning. Cows **cannot be lead** from the front. They are not sheep, which ***blindly*** follows the footsteps of the one walking ahead. Sheep going out of line is *generally* not possible (That's what they are *infamous* for) whether or not they are lead by shepherds. And the answer portrays *cowboys* stronger than *shepherds* which I'm not sure looking at other answers and some references as my homework. And I asked help understand the quote, I was not completely blank! :)

Comment: @J.R. And check out the accepted answer and this one. They are *exactly* opposite by all accounts.

Comment: @MaulikV - That's not so. They are alike in that they compare and contrast two leadership styles. Note that "front" and "rear" can be used literally (where the herder stands in relation to the animals) or figuratively (where a leader stands in relation to the subordinates). The point is that one style of leadership drives through intimidation, and the other leads through more gentle encouragement, and this answer explains that difference quite well. This and the accepted answer are only different in where the herder stands, which is hardly "exactly opposite by ALL accounts".

Answer (score -1):

Cowboys ride horses. They sit on the horses and tell them where to go. A shepherd, not just tells the cattle where to go but also walks with them. A shepherd kind of leader works hard with his team. A cowboy kind of leader just tells his team what to do. But does not work hard himself. I think that's what it means.